# perl CGI radio button form

Tags: forms, apache, perl, cgi

I have following CGI snippet from my code. its create textarea to type my message which i want to send, but i want to convert that into template style like "radio", so i select just radio button and it will inject whatever message into notification for customer, so i don't need to type message every time. just like template. Anybody has any example or code which can fix in my requirement?

```
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp;
...
...
$html .= $q->b("Customer Notification:") . $q->br;
    $html .= $q->textarea(-name=>'notification',
                          -rows=>4,
                          -columns=>60) . $q->p;

    $html .= $q->submit(-name=>' Send Notification ');
    $html .= "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ";
    $html .= $q->reset(-name=>' Reset to Original Value ');
    $html .= $q->p;
```

Comment: You appear to be using CGI.pm, [you shouldn't do that](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)

Comment: Yes i have updated my question

Comment: Quentin's point was that use of CGI.pm is discouraged and that the HTML generation functions you're using [have been deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

Comment: These codes are years, years code and need just small modification.. We can re-write it from scratch..it would be good if in existing code something possible, how about `radio_group`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, you should really consider using one of the other solutions found in [CGI::Alternatives](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.14/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm).

Nevertheless...

```
my %labels = (
    'comment'   => 'General Comment',
    'problem'   => 'Non-critical Problem',
    'emergency' => 'Critical Emergency',
);
$html .= $q->radio_group(
            -name=>'notification',
            -values=>['comment','problem','emergency'],
            -default=>'comment',
            -linebreak=>'true',
            -labels=>\%labels,
);
```

Comment: You codes looks good but question, I have 2 line email which i want to put it there, how that will fit there, LIke `We have emergency maintenances which require system down for X to Y time etc..`

Comment: If you want to submit those two lines as a form value, just make it the value of one of the radio buttons.  `-values=>['comment','problem','We have emergency maintenances...'],`